# Multithreading in c# how to use?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I never work with multithreading in c#. Can some body give me a simple code example to do this?

(c# with asp.net web application)

My intention is i want to read 10 values at a same time. So I'm going for multithreading concept. Is it right thing what I choose? Or is there any best way to approach?

Thank you,
nagu

Comment: Please describe the scenario a bit more in detail. Can you for instance show how you read these values in your code today? Or give an example of how you would do it in a regular, non-threaded manner?

Comment: Actually I havnt started the coding. Before going to start coding i need to confirm where i'm going in a right path or not? Just my intention is to read values from different websites (nothign but website text grabbing) at a same time. 

Hope you understand my problem

Comment: I will say this: Multithreading is not easy, so "a simple code example to do this" simply doesn't exist. You *must* know what you're doing if you're going to do bug-free multithreading.

Comment: @Nagu: I would still recommend you to start off by putting it together without multiple threads. Then, when you have code that does the job properly in a single threaded manner, post your question around this specific example, and you are likely to get resposes fitting that particular situation.

Comment: So how can i do this? I've n no.of methods and want to call those methods at the same time. So which is the best way?

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you read Joe Albahari's free e-book: [Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)

Comment: Good one + search stackoverflow as there are numerous questions about threading in .NET.

Comment: I think this is a console application. I want to implement threads concept in web applicaiton with asp.net and c#

Comment: ok thank you, but my in simple words my problem is i want to send sms to 100 members exactly at a same time (Ex : sharp 12:00 AM). Is it possible through multi threading in c#?

Comment: Ok thank you, But in simple words my problem is to sms for 1000 members at a same time (For Ex: 12:00 AM sharp) is it possible throu c# multithreading?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your response to Mitch's answer, it sounds like what you really want is to multicast your messages (one message to many addresses) as opposed to many simulatenous messages. What API are you using to send the message? Does it support multicast?

Answer (score 0):

A simple tutorial here: [http://www.codersource.net/csharp_tutorial_multithreading.html](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)

A good one is here: http://www.albahari.com/threading/

Answer (score 0):

MSDN is always a good place to start, with extensive information on just about everything, including threading.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173178.aspx

Also, a good tutorial on threading in C# is available here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740%28VS.71%29.aspx